# Website showing a different site when I connect to it via HTTPS

Tags: https

My website at alexwang.cf is for some reason showing danicv.me (as if I made a CNAME record for it) when I connect to it via **https.** Using HTTP it works just fine and shows up fine. I don't have any CNAME records, or redirects in cPanel. My .htaccess file is completely blank with nothing in it. My site is NOT php, but all HTML coded by me. However, visiting danicv.me does NOT redirect to MY site.
I'm using a SSL.com free trial SSL certificate. The chat support didn't help much, so I'm assuming this is either 1) an uncommon problem or 2) a relatively common problem, just not many people report it.

I am using shared hosting so I don't have SSH access.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I have uninstalled all of the SSL certificates, still showing danicv.me.

**Edit II** Now the subdomain home.alexwang.cf is working.
The root domain is still showing danicv.

**Edit III**: I've gotten in touch with the owner of danicv.me and I've found out that the domain https://lunarcp.com is also showing danicv.me.
So its a problem on his end, and we've solved this.
This thread can be locked.

Comment: @John Conde If this question is off topic, what Stack Exchange site would be able to answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

You should check with your host. It sounds like a mis-configured vhost on their end.

Your host may have different options for HTTPS (e.g. a paid upgrade) and may have shared IP addresses with misconfigured SNI.

Comment: That might be the case. 2 days ago HTTPS was working just fine, yesterday cPanel was down, and today it's messed up. So I think there's a connection there. I have already checked with my host, they said there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Point them to both versions of the URL, with screenshots to help confirm. Also point to https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/alexwang.cf showing some DNS propagation errors they should look at.

Comment: @user4673279 They say that nothing is wrong... except that it is not working... what part of that is nothing wrong?? Was working... not working... you did nothing... they have obvious problems between times... huh. Does it take a rocket scientist? The vhost is the likely issue. Ping 'em again and again. Escalate if you have to. But make sure that you have not made a mistake somewhere first. That could be embarrassing.